# Center Entire Site and Middle Align Nav

Tags: css, alignment

Is there a better way to center my entire site on the screen instead of using Margin-Top to push it down?

The other thing I'm having issues with is Vertical-align: middle; I've tried it a few times and cannot get the menu items to move into the middle of the screen. I read that I needed the inline-block and vertical-align: middle; on the links but I've tried it on the LI and anchors themselves but nothing seems to actually move them.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    background: #333;
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 150px;
}

.menu {
    width: 80px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 150px;
}

.menu ul {
    background: #000;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 60vh;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu li a {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

section {
    margin-left:80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stylesheets.css">
    
    <title>Vertical Menu Project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <nav class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <section class="hero">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5692127/pexels-photo-5692127.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500" alt="">
        </section>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To center a page, In most cases it is `body > .container { width: ...px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; }` where you have to decide what the width of the page must be.

Comment: To center the menu, try using `.menu { display: block; width: 100%; text-align: center; } .menu > ul { display: inline-block; width: auto; }` Then you have to set a equal width for each `<li>`

Comment: @bron Sorry I should have been more clear, I'm trying to center the Icons on the navbar to be in the middle of it. I've had to use Margin-top: to move them down because vertical align isn't working.

Regarding the center a page both vert / horz, this didn't seem to do anything for me. I tried it right about my .container css and removed the margin top I put in place and it just put everything back at the top.